# Access name of python objects

Tags: python, oop, names

I made a class to work with Heating wires:

```
class Heating_wire:

    def __init__(self, ro, L,d,alpha):

        self.ro = ro
        self.L = L
        self.d = d
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.RT = [1]
        self.vector_T = [1]
    def get_R20(self):
        self.R_20 =  self.ro*self.L/(np.pi*(self.d/2)**2)

    def  calcular_RT(self,vector_temp):
        self.vector_T = vector_temp
        self.RT =  [self.R_20*(1 + temp*self.alpha) for temp in vector_temp ]
        return self.RT
```

instantiate some objects:

```
kantal = Heating_wire(1.45,0.25,0.3,4e-5)
nicromo = Heating_wire(1.18,0.25,0.3,0.0004)
ferroniquel = Heating_wire(0.86,0.25,0.3,9.3e-4)

wires = [kantal,nicromo,ferroniquel]
```

And made a plot:

```
leg = []
vector_temp = np.linspace(20,1000,1000)
for wire in sorted(wires):
    wire.get_R20()
    wire.get_RT(vector_temp)
    line, = plt.plot(wire.vector_T,wire.RT)
    leg.append(line)
plt.legend(leg,sorted(wires))
```

The issue is that I'm not getting the right names in the legend but the reference to the objects:

[image]

If I add a name attribute

```
def __init__(self,name, ro, L,d,alpha):
    self.name = name
```

I can append the names

```
leg = []

names= []
vector_temp = np.linspace(20,1000,1000)
for wire in sorted(wires):
    wire.get_R20()
    wire.get_RT(vector_temp)
    line, = plt.plot(wire.vector_T,wire.RT)
    leg.append(line)
    names.append(wire.name)
plt.legend(leg,names,loc='best')
```

[image]

But I wonder if there is a simpler way t solve this using directly the names of the objects in the list of wires:

```
kantal = Heating_wire(1.45,0.25,0.3,4e-5)
nicromo = Heating_wire(1.18,0.25,0.3,0.0004)
ferroniquel = Heating_wire(0.86,0.25,0.3,9.3e-4)

wires = [kantal,nicromo,ferroniquel]
```

Comment: Try to implement either the `__repr__` or `__str__` methods for your class

Comment: Python objects don't have names. Variables have names, but the objects have no record of what variables refer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like this and there's no duplication:

```
wires = [
    Heating_wire("kantal", 1.45,0.25,0.3,4e-5),
    Heating_wire("nicromo", 1.18,0.25,0.3,0.0004),
    Heating_wire("ferroniquel", 0.86,0.25,0.3,9.3e-4)
]
```

To answer your question, no, objects cannot access the names they were given.